# python 2.7 fails to index line but gets letter instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

```
fromStr = 'start of show feature'
toString = 'end of show feature'

with open(filepath) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if fromStr in line:
            fromline = num

with open(filepath) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if toString in line:
            toline = num

fromline = fromline+1

f = open(filepath)
lines=f.readlines()
store =  lines[fromline:toline-1]
store1 = '\n'.join(store)
text = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in store1.splitlines() if ll.strip()])  # remove blank lines

string = 'enabled'

matched_lines = [line for line in text.split('\n') if string in line] #get matched lines
#matched_lines = list(set(matched_lines))  #get unique items only or remove duplicates (the result will be unordered for many items)
matched_lines = '\n'.join(matched_lines) #rearrange the lines in order
```

When i do
`print matched_lines`
I get

`dhcp                  1         enabled
hsrp_engine           1         enabled
interface-vlan        1         enabled
lacp                  1         enabled
ntp                   1         enabled
scpServer             1         enabled
sshServer             1         enabled
vpc                   1         enabled`

but if i try to index a line

`print matched_lines[0]`

i get

`d`

but i am expecting the first ine

`dhcp                  1         enabled`

Please let me know what do I have to do fix this.

Comment: How do you generate `matched_lines`?

Comment: Is `matched_lines` a list or tuple?

Comment: You only have one line, if you use `[0]` on it, it will return the first character.

Comment: @marcin i have update the question to show how i am getting the matched_lines.

Comment: @KlausD.  matched_lines contain 7 or more lines.

Comment: Before you joined them, it did.

Comment: `matched_lines = '\n'.join(matched_lines)`  this will make one string from your list. Dont do this, and you can get individual lines.

Comment: @Marcin please put it as a solution and i will mark is my answer. That seems to be the case and your suggestion is working for me.

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi I made the anwser from the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment:

matched_lines = '\n'.join(matched_lines) this will make one string from your list. Dont do this, and you can get individual lines.